# Adding padding between an image and text

Tags: html, css, image, icons, padding

I have an expanding list that initially only shows a title, but then if clicked on, it shows the description. I felt the list needed some sort of image to help illustrate that it needs clicked on to show more. With that said, I added a plus sign ---- please comment if a different icon would be better for this case----.

I feel that the title is way too close to the plus sign, so how can I add padding in between the plus sign and title? I already have padding in place for the title, so I am unsure of what to do.

This can be seen on my website:

http://realtorcatch.com/service

The code I have for this is:

```
.service_wrapper {
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 15px;
    width: 20%;
}
.service_list {
    margin-left: 20%;
}   
.service_title {
    padding: 15px 12px;
    margin: 0;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1em;
}
.service_title:hover {
    background-color: gray;
    color: blue;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.service_description { 
    display: none;
    padding: 8px 14px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-size: .9em;
}

<div class="service_list">
    <div class="service_wrapper">
         <div class="service_title"><img src="icons/plusSymbol.png" alt="Service" style="width:10px;height:10px;">Floors</div>
    <div class="service_description">The best floors!</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please comment if a better icon can be used for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give padding right in image like below and use minus (-) sign when slidedown and plus (+) respectively.

```
.service_title img {
padding-right:10px;
}
```

jsfiddle link [chick here](https://jsfiddle.net/w15kj1qg/1/)

Comment: So you are saying you think I should have a minus sign there instead of the plus?

Comment: That worked. Thank you very much! Would another icon be better for this?

Comment: No, plus sign is okay but when slide down make it minus sign. make sense

Comment: How could I change the image when it has been slid down?

Comment: can you please provide both image (plus/minus) link?

Comment: <img src="icons/plusSymbol.png">-----------<img src="icons/minusSymbol.png">.......https://icons8.com/web-app/for/all/plus%20symbol

Comment: I like how the minus sign comes up, but the description won't slide back up if clicked. Could this be made to work with toggle or do you think slideUp/Down is the best approach?

Comment: @Becky Please check my jsfiddle link slideup/slidedown is good